# OSX - Cancel click

Tags: macos, click

Plain and clear : How do you cancel a click after you press the mouse.
Say for example I press the mouse on a close button to close an application, but then I change my mind and want to cancel the closing. In windows you just drag out of the area and let go of the mouse, but that doesn't seem to work in OSX. Any ideas ?

NB : Using Mac OSX Yosemite

Comment: Works for me on OS X as well. Are you experiencing this in general or only in specific applications?

Answer (score 1):

I use the trackpad, and when I click in a wrong button, I continue to press the trackpad and trag to an other part of the interface.

But if this dosn't work with the mouse, you can press the cmd (⌘) symbol to cancel it. That work in my MacBook Pro under Yosemite.